# Excel: how to manually set alternating background color?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In a pivot table, only one column has alternating background color. The other columns have no background color. How do I manually set the alternating background color? So far, I have found no way of doing it except copying and pasting the format.

When I clicked "Banded Rows" in "Table Style Options" and selected different design, those banded rows changed accordingly. However, those non-banded row did not change. For example, the first two cells in Column C and Columns D to M were banded and changing table style would change them. However, Columns A, B, and Column C rows 3 and down were not banded. Changing table style had no effect on them.

Comment: Have you used *Home > Format as Table* on these rows? If you did, go to pane "Table design" and check "Banded Rows" instead of "Banded Columns".

Comment: I use Excel 2010. I cannot find Home > Format as Table and "Banded Rows" did not work. The "Banded Rows" removed the bands from those areas that were already banded. For those unbanded area, it did nothing.

Comment: I guess Excel no longer recognizes the unbanded areas as part of the table. I have tried resizing the table to include those unbanded areas to no avail.

Comment: Under PivotTable Design tab you can change table format.

Comment: I was only able to change color of those cells that were already banded. Those cells that were not banded stayed in white. For example, the first two cells in Column C were already banded. So, when I changed table design, their color also changed. However, Column C row 3 and down had white background and changing table design had no effect on them.

Answer (score 0):

Alternating background colors in Excel for ordinary tables
can be set via the ribbon.

As in the Office article
[Apply shading to alternate rows or columns in a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-shading-to-alternate-rows-or-columns-in-a-worksheet-a443b0f5-2025-42f6-9099-5de09c05e880),
there are two methodologies for alternating background colors:

- Conditional formatting
- Excel table styles

The second is found inside the pane "Table design", where two options are found:
"Banded Rows" and "Banded Rows", where the second one seems to answer the question:

[image]

For pivot tables, the related Microsoft article is
[Design the layout and format of a PivotTable](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/design-the-layout-and-format-of-a-pivottable-a9600265-95bf-4900-868e-641133c05a80),
where the option is found still in the Design tab, but in the
PivotTable Style Options group, and is still called
Banded Rows and Banded Columns.

[image]

Comment: When I clicked "Banded Rows" in "Table Style Options" and selected different design, those banded rows changed accordingly. However, those non-banded row did not change. For example, changing design had no effect on Column A and B, which were not banded. The first two cells in Column C and Columns D to M were banded and changing table style would change them. However, Column C rows 3 and down were not banded. Changing table style had no effect on them.

Comment: What do you see if you first select all your data?

Comment: Banded still banded, non-banded still non-banded. I selected the entire pivot table.

Comment: I hope you have a backup: Perhaps removing first all other formatting would help. This is done in *Home > Editing > Clear > Clear Formats*. Formulas could also affect banding.

Comment: I found that copied banded areas and pasted format to non-banded areas would turn non-banded areas into banded areas, i.e. Table Style Option would then work on those previously non-banded areas. I hesitated to do that because that would mess up other formats such as Date, Currency, etc..

Comment: Then it looks like some formatting of these cells is blocking the banding. I don't know your spreadsheet enough to give better advice.

Comment: I believe besides conditional formatting, Home/Fill Color, and Banded Rows, there is one more way of setting background color of cells and it is missing in the non-banded cells. I just can't find out what it is.